# UIRefreshControl with low height UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a view which contains another view on the top part, which I'm using to show some basic information. It has about 40% of the total view height. Below that "header" view, I'm using a UICollectionView which is scrollable. Now I've added a UIRefreshControl to my UICollectionView, but refreshing does never occur, because the user can't pull down the UICollectionView that far. When I reduce the height of the top view, it starts working because there's enough space to pull the collectionview down then.

Here's how I'm adding the refreshControl:

```
    self.matchDetailRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.matchDetailRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MatchDetailViewController.fetchAll), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.collectionView!.addSubview(self.matchDetailRefreshControl)
    self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Have a look at this screenshot for reference:
[image]

As you can see, the UIRefreshControl doesn't get fully filled, while my finger is already at the bottom of the screen.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try to use this control : https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh hope you will get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement scrollViewDidScroll.
If the scrollView's contentOffset is past a certain point, then implement your refresh programmatically using beginRefreshing()

eg (with the refresh control connected to an outlet named 'refreshControl')

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset

    let yOffset = currentOffset.y

    if yOffset < -30.0 && !refreshControl.refreshing {
        refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    }
}
```

don't forget to set the scrollView's delegate to self if you haven't already

edit: sorry it's beginRefreshing(), not startRefreshing().

Comment: How simple... I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: You should call `refreshControl.sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged` to actually call the refresh method.